# Сложение массивов путем объединения

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп

Понимаю, что много вопросов на эту тему уже писали. Мне нужно написать программу, которая будет объединять два массива, записывая в 3. Нету возможности написать код по другому, нужно правильно оформить этот, чтобы он складывал. 2 массива я уже отсортировал, записал один в переменную. Второй не могу сделать, чтобы он сравнивал с первым и записывал в третий те, каких нет. Ещё я не могу сделать правильную запись в третий. Не понимаю, как это сделать корректно.

```
SortArray& operator + (const Array &x) const override //объединение, тут нужна помощь
{
    const SortArray& temp = dynamic_cast<const SortArray&>(x);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        arr[sz] = arr[i];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < temp.sz; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < sz; j++){
            if (arr[i] = arr[j])
                break;

        arr[temp.sz] = arr[sz];
        }
    }
    SortArray *result = new SortArray (temp.arr, temp.sz + sz);
    return *result;
}

void foreach() // этот метод сортирует массив, работает корректно
    const
    override
{
    double temp;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz - 1; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < sz - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
            {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Ссылка на всю программу](https://onlinegdb.com/SkNA24vQN)

Comment: Возвращать из оператора ссылку на объект в памяти (`SortArray *result = new SortArray (temp.arr, temp.sz + sz);
    return *result;`) - идея, скажем прямо, не из лучших...

Comment: Я хотел создать третий независимый массив, для которого можно задать размер, но с этим я справился максимально неудачно

Comment: Обычно operator+ не нуждается в модификаций споих операндов. Для чего вы сортировали, какие повторяющийся элемнты вы не хотите копировать?... Не понятно ничего. Для таких целей лучше подойдет функция, чем  operator+

Comment: @ARHovsepyan оператор + тут обозначается как сложение, его можно заменить на название add. Вся суть, что нужно сложить два массива с помощью объединения (как дизъюнкция). То есть все элементы из первого и второго массивов должны быть в третьем массиве, каждый в одном экземпляре.

Comment: Вам нужно воспользоваться стандартным алгоритмом слияния отсортированных массивов: проход сразу по двум массивам, двумя итераторами, с выбором минимального элемента из двух на каждом шаге, но добавить модификацию для уникальных значений: если встретили элемент, равный последнему добавленному в новый массив, то игнорировать его.

Answer (score 0):

```
SortArray *result = new SortArray (temp.arr, temp.sz + sz);
size_t i = 0;
for (; i < sz; ++i)
        result->arr[i] = (temp.arr[i] < arr[i])
                ? temp.arr[i] : arr[i];
for(; i < result->sz; ++i)
    result->arr[i] = temp.arr[0];  
return *result;
```

Comment: Ваша логика мне понятна, но в программе никакие изменения не работают вообще. То есть как бы я не менял этот фрагмент (в т.ч. адаптировав ваш фрагмент) вывод все тот же.

Comment: выполните очистку состояния  проекта  build -> clean all.  Если что не так, прибегните к помощи отладчика . Он поможет вам найти ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, особое спасибо @iksuy за хорошую мысль. Рабочий, но достаточно сырой код приложу. Если хотите его использовать, его нужно будет доработать.

```
SortArray& operator + (const Array &x) const override
{
    const SortArray& temp = dynamic_cast<const SortArray&>(x);
    size_t i = 0, j = 0, f = sz, s = temp.sz, th = 0;
    while ((i < f) && (j <= s))
    {
        if (arr[i] == temp.arr[j])
        {
            arr[th] = arr[i];
            th++;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else if(arr[i] < temp.arr[j])
        {
            arr[th] = arr[i];
            th++;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[th] = temp.arr[j];
            th++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    while (i < f)
    {
        arr[th] = arr[i];
        th++;
        i++;
    }
    while (j < s)
    {
        arr[th] = temp.arr[j];
        th++;
        j++;
    }
    SortArray *result = new SortArray (arr, th);
    return *result;
}
```

Важно! Этот метод изменяет один из входящих в него массивов, что отрицательно может сказаться на конечном результате. Ещё этот метод работает только для упорядоченных массивов.

Answer (score -2):

Это что:

```
arr[sz] = arr[i]
```

и тому подобное?

Добавлять можно  с помощью std::vector<>.push_back(...).

Извините, что отвечаю, а не просто комментирую, не хватает репутации.

ps

```
my_vector<T>& my_vector<T>::operator += (const my_vector<T> x) {
    for (vector<T>::iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); i++)
        push_back(*it);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Насколько я ориентируюсь в коде, push_back используется только для контейнера типа вектор, у меня их тут нет

Comment: Вы на вопрос ответьте. Про stl мягкий намёк, что у Вас много ошибок. Предлагаете за Вас всё сделать? Смотрели Двое из ларца?

Comment: Я не прошу сделать всё за меня. Нужно лишь направить в нужном направлении. `arr[sz] = arr[i]` это присвоение существующего массива в новый, но сейчас я увидел, что это полная чушь. Да, мне нужно с помощью циклов и сравнения записать в третий массив объединенные первый и второй. Но у меня с этим проблемы, т.к. я никак не пойму работы с виртуальными классами и ссылками.

Comment: Вы копируете весь массив в один элемент массива arr[sz], который, к тому же, не выделен. push_back позволяет добавлять так, что память выделяется автоматически. Мне проще написать на stl, чем сделать то, что Вы просите.

Comment: Вообще это действие происходит в цикле, и этот массив с этим размером уже существует, я вот понял, что я от начала этого цикла до конца присваиваю ему его же значения, а не в новый массив

Comment: Ну и где у Вас изменяется в цикле sz? А по поводу "массив с этим размером существует" -- Вы же сами меняете ДО размера. Хотя, возможно Ваше sz не то, что обычно возвращают методы типа length, size, count.

Comment: Дописал свой ответ. Делов-то.